# Blending image with background in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, django

In the following HTML document, the Microsoft logo does not blend with the background image. Does anyone know how you can blend the logo with the background image or remove the logo's background colour? I have tried using the command mix-media-mode: multiply but the image still did not blend properly. Thank you for your help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <style>
body {
  background-image: url('https://i.pinimg.com/564x/09/01/f0/0901f088d78988a5b6bc66af7cfbfec8.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;    
}
</style> 
    </head>
    <body> 
       <img src= "https://i.pinimg.com/564x/09/05/85/090585401505f54e69a1a5e218759171.jpg" height="35px" alt="">
  
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sourround it by a div and give an opacity.
You can use
mix-blend-mode: multiply;
also for the body with the parameter for your needs

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
<style>
    body {
        background-image: url('https://i.pinimg.com/564x/09/01/f0/0901f088d78988a5b6bc66af7cfbfec8.jpg');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-size: cover;    
    }
    #logo{
        opacity:0.2;
    }
</style> 
    </head>
    <body> 
        <div id="logo">
            <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/564x/09/05/85/090585401505f54e69a1a5e218759171.jpg" height="35px" alt="">
        <div/>
</body>
</html>
```